# How do i split my Pre_covid data into testing and training data. My Pre_covid dataset is in a date format

Tags: r

Every time i try to split the dataset into testing and training, i cant get through. My Pre_covid dataset is in a time series format and when i try to split it, the error message says `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. My Pre_covid dataset starts and ends as below.

```
start          end 
"2001-09-01" "2020-01-01"
```

The following are my codes for my Pre_covid dataset.
Please help to show how to split this into a 70/30 training and testing sets.thanks

```
# Create the "Pre-Covid" dataset

pre_covid_start_date <- as.Date("1/9/2001", format = "%d/%m/%Y")  # September 1, 2001
pre_covid_end_date <- as.Date("1/1/2020", format = "%d/%m/%Y")    # January 1, 2020
Pre_covid <- c(start = pre_covid_start_date, end = pre_covid_end_date)
Pre_covid
```